# Spring Interceptors are called twice in mixed configuration (annotation-based and SimpleUrlHandlerMapping)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

We have a Spring web application with mixed configuration for Spring 2.x and Spring 3.1 mvc objects. There are same set of interceptors defined by *mvc:interceptors* tag and *SimpleUrlHandlerMapping* interceptor property. Our thought was that each handler mapping applies its own interceptors only, but we notice that on Spring 2 urls the interceptors are called twice. When we remove the interceptors from the *SimpleUrlHandlerMapping* the interceptors are still applied which means *mvc:interceptors* are effective anyway. Below please see the snippet of configuration:

mvc-config.xml

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <mvc:interceptors>
    <ref bean="clientDataInterceptor" />
    <ref bean="securityInterceptor" />
    <ref bean="resourceCleanupInterceptor" />
  </mvc:interceptors>
```

springdispatcher.xml

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
    <property name="mappings">
      <props>
       <prop key="/path/**">myController</prop>
...
      </props> 
    </property>
    <property name="interceptors">
      <list>
        <ref bean="clientDataInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="securityInterceptor" />
        <ref bean="resourceCleanupInterceptor" />
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/springdispatcher.xml, /WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Appreciate any insight why this is happening and if it is safe to simply remove Spring 2.x interceptor list.

Comment: I don't think I understand. You have one application which has both `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` with some interceptors and, also, `mvc:interceptors`. The [documentation says](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-config-interceptors) that `<mvc:interceptors\>` applies to ALL HandlerMapping beans. It can be configured to apply to only some paths but the way you have it defined it's for all paths.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. While you seem to be right but in the document it doesn't explicitly mention that <mvc:interceptors> is applied to all HandlerMapping beans. From the section you pointed "You can configure HandlerInterceptors or WebRequestInterceptors to be applied to all incoming requests or restricted to specific URL path patterns". It doesn't talk about the behavior when there are multiple HandlerMapping beans.

Answer (score 0):

You have a handler mapping that matches some URLs (like `/path/**` in your case). Also, you can have another handler mapping that matches some other URLs (like `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` mapping to bean names or `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`). The point is that with your mappings you define associations between URLs and handlers. `<mvc:interceptors/>` apply to all URLs if no include or exclude patterns are defined.

I looked in the source code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/InterceptorsBeanDefinitionParser.java) and especially [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/MappedInterceptor.java#L122) and if there are no `excludePatterns` defined then code goes on and checks for `includePatterns`. If these are null, as well, then the interceptor matches. So, I'm reading this that if I define an interceptor using `<mvc:interceptors/>` and I'm not giving it any patterns to include or exclude then that interceptor applies to all URLs.

Comment: This still looks a bit strange to me. As I understand, interceptors are property of HandlerMapping beans and for any given URL only one HandlerMapping is used. In our case the URL is resolved by SimpleUrlHandlerMapping. How come <mvc:interceptors> come into play? Could that be an implementation bug in Spring?

Comment: Take a look at this [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10921). While the description of the issue doesn't provide configuration sample or details, there is a comment from Rossen that seems to cover the exact scenario you have.